# Can't Override the default css style in ng-multiselect-dropdown in angular 6

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using ng-multiselect-dropdown.I want to change the default style but it cannot override.I tried to given the style in index.html,angular.json,style.css files and also i tried inline style but nothing was changed.

Css tried:

```
 ng-multiselect-dropdown .multiselect-dropdown > .dropdown-btn{
font-size:12px;
}
```

ts:

```
styles: [".multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn{
        font-size:12px;
        }"]
```

another way:

```
multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn{
    font-size:12px;
    }
```

another way:

```
 multiselect-parent .dropdown-btn{
    font-size:12px;
    }
```

html:

```
 <ng-multiselect-dropdown  [placeholder]="'Select'" [data]="xxx" [(ngModel)]="xxx" name="Name" [settings]="dropdownSettings" [textField]="'Name'">
 </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

How to achieve this?I tried everything related to this question.So please don't say duplicate question.

Comment: Please share your HTML code.

Comment: Updated the code above

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please use css like this to override default value

```
ng-multiselect-dropdown /deep/ .multiselect-dropdown > .dropdown-btn{
   font-size:12px !important;
}
```

### Alternative

```
:host /deep/ .multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn {
   font-size:12px !important;
}
```

### Add to global style `src/styles.css`

```
.custom-font-size .multiselect-dropdown .dropdown-btn {
   font-size:12px !important;
}
```

then add this class `custom-font-size` to dropdown component

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown class="custom-font-size"></ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Comment: Please set important. /deep/ is used to apply css to another compontent who css is written in it own template css. Please look into this https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: I tried both of your code but unluckily does not work.

Comment: Please update a files component names in your questions. I tried and it is working fine

Comment: I can't get you which component names

Comment: Hey Its Working.Thank you for Your help.

Comment: Accept the answer if you are satisfied

Comment: Accepted the answer.Thank You

Comment: Hi.the above answer is working.But i have another issue now.In pop up window I used the same multiselect dropdown to show selected values in that the style is not changed.Both are in the same page If any suggestions for this

Comment: Its working with small change class is already occupied with "undefined ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty" so gave the style using id.Thank you once again.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you must be sure that this component is added inside of your component, because some components are added to body. 
If this component has been added to your component you can use the css below inside your component css file:

```
:host::ng-deep ng-multiselect-dropdown .multiselect-dropdown > .dropdown-btn{
     font-size:12px;
}
```

If this has been added to body the only way is to put your css in styles.css file.

```
ng-multiselect-dropdown .multiselect-dropdown > .dropdown-btn{
     font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: The defalut style is in node modules folder

Comment: No, It's in src folder

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` inside your component decorator where you are using this `ng-multiselect-dropdown`.

> Angular comes with view encapsulation built in, which enables us to
>   use Shadow DOM or even emulate it. There are three view encapsulation
>   types:
>
> - ViewEncapsulation.None - No Shadow DOM at all. Therefore, also no style encapsulation.
> - ViewEncapsulation.Emulated - No Shadow DOM but style encapsulation emulation.
> - ViewEncapsulation.Native - Native Shadow DOM with all it’s goodness.

Eg-:-

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my-component.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: Nothing was changed

Comment: You need to add this in the component where you are using your `ng-multiselect`

Comment: Yes.I used In the component where i used ng-multiselect-dropdown.But its not work

Answer (score 0):

> This will definitely help you

> override selected item

```
:host ::ng-deep {
   .multiselect-dropdown {
    .dropdown-btn{
     .selected-item{
       background: #00b8aa !important;
       border: #00b8aa !important;
     }
    }
  }
}
```

> override checkbox

```
:host::ng-deep ng-multiselect-dropdown .multiselect-item-checkbox 
  input[type=checkbox]:checked + div:before {
  background:#00b8aa !important;
}

:host::ng-deep ng-multiselect-dropdown .multiselect-item-checkbox 
    input[type=checkbox] + div:before {
    border: 2px solid #00b8aa !important;
}
```